# Python: change file/folder attributes in windows OS

Tags: python, cmd

I have made a folder using python3 script, and to apply multiple attributes (+h +s) to the folder I have to run ATTRIB command in Command Prompt.
But I want to know how it can be done from the same python3 script.

```
import os

os.makedir("C:\\AutoSC")

# Now I want the code to give the same result such that I have opned CMD and writen following command
# C:\> attrib +h +s AutoSC

# Also show in the code, necessary imported modules
```

I want the folder to be created and immediately hidden as system folder.
Which is not visible even after show hidden files.

Comment: Check this [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system). After creating the directory you can execute `os.system('attrib +h +s AutoSC')`.

Comment: If you want to avoid making a new process, you could install `pywin32` from PyPI at https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/ and use the `win32file` module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the subprocess module or use os.system to send commands directly to OS.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(["ls","-l"])# in linux, for windows, it may change.
```

```
import os
os.system('attrib +h +s AutoSC')
```

Comment: Can repeted use of   os.system("command")   be used in python to work as a batch(.bat) file

Comment: issue a for loop.