# Add/Update an attribute of a directory in Windows 10 using python

Tags: python, windows, operating-system, directory-structure, microsoft-file-explorer

I want to update the **Length** attribute of a directory in windows 10 using python. How can I do it?

For example, consider the following image:

[image]

I want to update the **Length** attribute of `Folder 1`, `Folder 2`, etc., or add a new attribute called, let's say, *`Duration`*.

Is it possible to achieve this using python?

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick search and length displays the time (hours, minutes & seconds) of a media file. Length doesn't apply to folders.

[length example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FspOJ.png)

Comment: Yes, that is for a .mp4 file. But what I am looking for is a way to manually add a value for any attribute. Doesn't have to be length necessarily.

Comment: looks like you can use the os module for this. But you will have to get the windows command to edit the attribute of the file. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57241347/python-change-file-folder-attributes-in-windows-os